# How to make a affine transform matrix to a perspective transform matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matrix, affinetransform

From code

```
rotation = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((0, 0), 47.65, 1.0)
```

I got a rotation transform matrix like:

```
[[ 0.67365771  0.7390435   0.        ]
 [-0.7390435   0.67365771  0.        ]]
```

Since rotation is a special case of affine transform, I think this is a valid affine transform matrix, am I right?

Since affine transform is a special case of perspective transform, I also think this matrix will be a valid perspective transform matrix, if I make some modification based on it.

So I tried to add 1 more row to make it shape as 3 x 3.

```
newrow = numpy.array([numpy.array([1, 1, 1])])  # [[0 0 0]]
rotation3 = numpy.append(rotation, newrow, axis=0)
```

print(rotation3):

```
[[ 0.67365771  0.7390435   0.        ]
 [-0.7390435   0.67365771  0.        ]
 [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]
```

But `rotation3` does not seem to work properly as a perspective matrix, here is how I tested it:

```
rotated_points = cv2.perspectiveTransform(points, rotation3)
```

`rotated_points` does not look like a rotaion of `points`

Is [1, 1, 1] the correct row 3, should I also change row 1 and 2? and how can I do it?

Comment: I think 3 row should be [0, 0, 1], can you try this ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are right, the affine transform is a special case of the perspective transform.

The perspective transform of a identity matrix results in no change to the output:
(identity 3x3 matrix)

```
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,1]
```

So if you want a affine transformation matrix to grow to a perspective one you want to add the last line of this identity matrix.

Your example would look like:

```
 [ 0.67365771  0.7390435   0. ]
 [-0.7390435   0.67365771  0. ]
 [ 0.          0.          1. ]
```

Applying the above perspective mat has the same effect as if you would apply a affine transform with:

```
 [ 0.67365771  0.7390435   0.  ]
 [-0.7390435   0.67365771  0.  ]
```

--> have a look at

- [affie transformation wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#/media/File:2D_affine_transformation_matrix.svg)
- [Opencv generate identity matrix](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a2cf9b9acde7a9852542bbc20ef851ed2)
- [identity matrix wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)